# What is the difference between <%= ... %> and <% ... %> in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Does it have something to do with output?

So, `<%= ...code... %>` is used for outputting after code is executed, and `<% ...code... %>` is only used for executing the code?

Comment: FYI: This is the format of ERB (or Erubis), which is one of the templating languages used by Rails. If you were using Haml for your templating, you would never see this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) templating markup (one of many templating languages supported by Rails). This markup:

```
<% ... %>
```

is used to evaluate a Ruby expression. Nothing is done with the result of that expression, however. By contrast, the markup:

```
<%= ... %>
```

does the same thing (runs whatever Ruby code is inside there) but it calls `to_s` on the result and **replaces the markup with the resulting string**.

In short:

```
<% just run code %>
<%= run code and output the result %>
```

For example:

```
<% unless @items.empty? %>
  <ul>
    <% @items.each do |item| %>
      <li><%= item.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul> 
<% end %>
```

*In contrast, here's some Haml markup equivalent to the above:*

```
- unless @items.empty?
  %ul
    - @items.each do |item|
      %li= item.name
```

Answer (score 4):

Both execute the Ruby code contained within them. However, the different is in what they do with the returned value of the expression. `<% ... %>` will do nothing with the value. `<%= ... %>` will output the return value to whatever document it is executed in (typically a `.erb` or `.rhtml` document).

Something to note, `<%= ... %>` will automatically escape any HTML contained in text. If you want to include any conditional HTML statements, do it outside the `<% ... %>`.

```
<%= "<br />" if need_line_break %> <!-- Won't work -->

<% if need_line_break %>
<br />
<% end %> <!-- Will work -->
```

Answer (score 3):

`<%=` is used to output the value of a single expression, e.g.

```
<%= object.attribute %>
<%= link_to 'Link Title', link_path %>
```

while `<%` is used to execute arbitrary Ruby code.

Comment: Here's the documentation: [ERB - Recognized Tags](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#label-Recognized+Tags)