# what is the difference between <%= and <%=# in Ruby on Rails 3 for a javascript_include

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I came across a javascript include that looks like this -

```
<%#= javascript_include_tag 'someJavaScript' %>
```

I am not familiar with the # symbol in this call, what is the purpose of it? It seems to work the same with and without the # symbol.

I found this stackoverflow question similar and helpful but does not deal with the # symbol - 
[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247480/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: I have seen # before =, which means Ruby comment

Comment: It's used to comment out the code inside erb tags.

Comment: uhg, so simple.  That's what I initially thought but then I still saw the js in the file.  It must be included from another spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` comments out the following ruby statements inside the erb block, so the `javascript_include_tag` statement will not run.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes it's the simplest answer staring you in the face.