# whole RUBY hashmap printed out after ".each" loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I am iterating over a Hashmap of type . Works pretty well. My problem is, it prints out the whole Hashmap as String after the wanted output.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYokS.png)

What is happening? How can i prevent my app from doing that?

Edit: sorry for being silly.. totally forgot that!

source-code:

```
<div style="display: inline-block">
   <%= @tag_color_hash.each do |tag, color| %>
       <%= f.label tag, :style => "border-color: #{color}", :class => 'tags'%>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you attach source code? In Ruby irb it displayed last thing returned, but it's not irb.

Comment: If you're seeing this in a Rails console or web debugger, then I wouldn't worry about it. As @PatNowak says, the object gets printed out in the REPL after a line is executed, but if you're visiting your app on a webpage, this won't happen.

Comment: I'm visiting my page on a local server (localhost:****/foo/bar). so this shouldn't happen, right?

how can i avoid this?

the hash which gets printed out is: @tag_color_hash

Comment: Don't use `<%=` on the line with `.each`. Just `<%`

Comment: Thank y'all!! i didn't see the '=', even if that happened to me before.
can you write this as answer?

Comment: Nah, just delete the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this because you've included a `=` sign in your `.each` loop. When you write `<%=` you're telling the `.erb` interpreter that what's inside of the brackets is going to get displayed on the page. Change the line

```
<%= @tag_color_hash.each do |tag, color| %>
```

to

```
<% @tag_color_hash.each do |tag, color| %>
```

and your problem should get fixed. [Here's a link to a useful StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247480/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-ruby-on-rails).