# Ruby on Rails: Printing strings while looping inside a ruby block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a Ruby On Rails newbie, coming from PHP background. I have this code:

```
<%= 
form_for(@user, :url => new_user_path) do |form|
    form.label :name, 'Name: '
    form.text_field(:name)
    form.label :age, 'Age: '
    form.text_field(:age)
end
%>
```

The only string being printed/returned is the last part/line, since that is how ruby blocks work as I understood. Now in this next code, it prints it all.

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => new_user_path) do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :name, 'Name: ' %>
    <%= form.text_field(:name) %>
    <%= form.label :age, 'Age: ' %>
    <%= form.text_field(:age) %>
<% end %>
```

How can I make all the tags be printed without using `<%=` and `%>` on every line. I'm looking for such since I'm from PHP, and if can, It can make the code more readable and uncluttered for me. Or maybe I might be doing it wrong perhaps? I already tried building the string, then place the variable at the end of the block to be returned by the loop, like so:

```
<%= 
form_build = String.new
form_for(@user, :url => new_user_path) do |form|
    form_build += form.label :name, 'Name: '
    form_build += form.text_field(:name)
    form_build += form.label :age, 'Age: '
    form_build += form.text_field(:age)
    form_build.to_s
end
%>
```

But the string printed was being enclosed in html comment code (`<!--` `-->`) in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the way [Rails works and is using templating markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247480/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-ruby-on-rails) in views.

`<%= var %>` will ouput the variable

`<% Ruby code %>` is a wrapper for your ruby code. It will not output anything.

The form code above outputs tags, so you need each line. I am not sure there is a way to do what you want, but that sounds like a lot of hassle for something already working well.

Coming from PHP, just "Keep calm and Trust the Force"!